# Can a visual studio extension install other visual studio extensions?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Basically what the question says.

Our company has a small suite of Visual Studio extensions we need to install. It's a bit of a pain and we just try to keep a list. When new ones are needed we send out an email or whatever.

Among these extensions we have written our own which has some home grown templates and tools.

Would we be able to have our visual studio extension install other visual studio extensions the same way a Nuget package can depend on other Nuget packages?

Comment: Have you created your own private extension feed?

Comment: Hmm, no, but we have a MyGet feed for Nuget packages, and I believe it can be used as an extension feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [Private Galleries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266746.aspx) where you can host a feed of all of your extensions. When you update your extensions you can update the feed, and the updates will appear in Extension Manager as any other extension does from the main gallery. You can also create an extension that defines this gallery if you don't want your users adding the path manually.

(The direct answer to your question is it is also possible to embed VSIXes in VSIXes, but I don't think that's what you Really Want™ here since it has a bunch of caveats.)